# syntax error in Form clause Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

```
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Public dr As OleDbDataReader
Public user As String
Public pass As String
Public type As String
Protected Sub Unnamed6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "H:\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\database.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString


    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim g As String = Request.Form("txtusername2").ToString()
        Dim p As String = Request.Form("txtpassword2").ToString()
        Dim str As String
        str = "select * from user-table where username='" & g & "'"


        'pDT = databaseConnector.RunSqlQuery(fulltxtSQL)
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            user = dr("username").ToString
            pass = dr("password").ToString
            type = dr("Type").ToString
        End While
        MsgBox(type)

        If pass = p Then
            Session("username") = g
            MsgBox(Session("username"))

            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

            MsgBox("thank you for loging in")
        End If
        myConnection.Close()

        Exit Sub

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.Trim, MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End Try

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

syntax error in Form clause am trying to save the database variables so i can use them to compare with the textbox 
my database name is database.accdb 
table name: user-table
fields : username, password, Type

Comment: try `[user-table]` most dbs dont like dashes in table names; alternatively, use a table-name which doesnt-have  hyphens-in-it

Comment: okay now the code works but once it reaches the last message box it jumps to catch and mentions thread was being aborted

Comment: Separate your data access logic from your UI/application logic. Mixing the two is messing up your code right now.

Comment: @switche  There is nothing wrong.  Response.Redirect throws a ThreadAbortException.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: okay i think that i have solved the problem thank you all for the help